# The letter x is not recognised as a letter on this site

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding

I have a client's website selling trailers of different kinds. There are different sizes of trailers which is represented by 10x5 trailer of 6x4 trailers and likewise.

We use the alphabet 'x' to denote 10x5 or 6x4.

The website uses UTF-8 character encoding.

However, when we search '10x5' on [this page](https://www.balancetrailers.com.au/products-category/10x5-tandem-trailers/), it shows no result despite having 10x5 mentioned on the page several times. However, if I use different competitors pages and search using the same term, it actually shows the number of times that term is used.

What could be wrong with the page or website? Is it encoding or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page does not use `x` (LATIN SMALL LETTER X), it uses `×` (MULTIPLICATION SIGN). This isn't an encoding problem; the page uses a different character.

Comment: Actually I wrote the content on that page using the letter x on my macOS, so no idea how it got converted into a multiplication sign. Could this be related to mac and Windows OS?

Comment: Very unlikely. Something in your deployment pipeline is converting it.